# Batch or VBS copy to clipboard

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am looking for a way to copy the text "Hello world" to the clipboard using either VBS or batch. I've done a lot of research but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @halfer Both bat and vbs are Windows-only.

Comment: Newer versions of Windows have the `CLIP` command to write to the clipboard. `echo Hello world|clip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) proposed you can use :

```
echo string|clip
```

thought this will set one enter at the end of the string.
To strip the enter you can use this:

```
mshta "javascript:Code(close(clipboardData.setData('text','string')));"
```

Comment: Would this also strip the crlf? `SET /P ".=Hello World"<nul|clip`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an html object to retrieve the contents of the clipboard:

```
' Get clipboard text
Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Clipboardtext = objHTML.ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text")
MsgBox Clipboardtext,vbInformation,"Get Clipboard"

sText = "Hello World"
'Here we set the string sText into Clipboard
Ws.Run "mshta.exe ""javascript:clipboardData.setData('text','" & Replace(Replace(sText, "\", "\\"), "'", "\'") & "');close();""", 0, True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't easily achievable using batch or VBScript.

To access clipboard, you need to use [a series of Windows APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649014(v=vs.85).aspx), which is not directly possible with either batch or VBScript. Your best bet could be writing a CLI program (helper program), then call it in yout batch / VBS.

Comment: Looks like they want to write to the clipboard which can easily be done with the `CLIP` command. Should be on WIndows 7 and above.

Comment: @Squashman I'll explore it tomorrow with my Windows 10 v1709.